# MongoDB find count of all possible 'columns' within a collection

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to find all possible number of 'columns' or json properties available in a collection? (I know it's not correct to call them columns, but just for the ease of understanding)

For example, all the following documents are in the same collection called 'people':

```
{"Name": "bob", "Profession": "IT", "Height": 200},
{"Name": "simon", "Weight": 100, "IQ": 120},
{"Name": "james", "Weight": 130, "Glasses": "Yes"}
```

The possible 'columns' here are: Name, Profession, Height, Weight, IQ and Glasses. A total of 6.

Is there any way I can do an operation which gets this count of 6? (extra useful if there's also a pymongo variant)

I'm wanting to transfer data from MongoDB into a table format, and knowing the overall number of columns the table can have is useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this aggregation query to get your desired result:

The trick here is to use `$objectToArray` to get the keys as values. Then remove the key `_id` (if exists) and group to  get the total.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "keys": {
        "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$keys"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "keys.k": {
        "$ne": "_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$keys.k",
      "total": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "total": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NPJPIw1ygF3)

**Edit:**

Another way to avoid `$unwind` and double `$group` id this query:

The idea is the same as before, use `$objectToArray` to get the keys as `key.k` and then `$group` all values and add into an array.
Then get the size of the array after to do some calculations: A `$reduce` to flatten the array and `$filter` to not get the `_id` field.

Note that if you want to count the `_id` you can simply remove the `$filter` stage [like this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qIpv2rTaO64)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "keys": {
        "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "keys": {
        "$addToSet": "$keys.k"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "keys": {
        "$size": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": {
              "$reduce": {
                "input": "$keys",
                "initialValue": [],
                "in": {
                  "$setUnion": [
                    "$$value",
                    "$$this"
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "cond": {
              "$ne": [
                "$$this",
                "_id"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XEqwQc1Wa3_)